# Getting 500 internal server error while using fileConfig in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylons

I am new to python, and started to work on it for web application development. So after taking the full code from SVN, I have configured it on my local (**Windows 7**). After configuring vhost for apache properly, I have gone through the following code in wsgi file:

```
    import os, sys
    from paste.script.util.logging_config import fileConfig

    baseDir='D:/myapp'
    configFile = os.path.join(baseDir, 'development.ini')

    sys.path.append(baseDir)

    fileConfig(configFile)

    from paste.deploy import loadapp
    application = loadapp('config:%s' % configFile)
```

The problem is that I got 500 internal server error while using the above code, but if I comment the
 **from paste.script.util.logging_config import fileConfig** and **fileConfig(configFile)** lines, It works properly.

Can anyone tell what is the use of **fileConfig()** and why I face 500 error problem while using it.

I am using **pylon framework** and **python 2.7.3**.

Comment: You should check the apache error logs to get the full error traceback output.

Comment: What if you simply launch this script via python?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a check:

```
if os.path.exists(configFile): 
    ...
```

Or if file exists:

```
try:
    fileConfig(configFile)
except Exception as e:
    print('There was a horrible error: {}'.format(e))
```

But to fully understand the problem, see the apache error log with full error traceback.

Comment: BasicWolf: +1 for your logical answer. But can u plz tell me what is the use of fileConfig() at all.

Comment: Well, it simply loads the pre-defined configuration from a file. If the file exists, but `fileConfig()` still throws an error, it is probably a syntax or other kind of error in the loaded configuration file.